# Error Contoller Howto : Spring-boot + Spring-Data-Rest

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Spring Boot with Spring Data Rest - how to use a custom error handler. 
Created an error controller  I tried to skip the default error handler by using following code.
Why it is not working!

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { BasicErrorController.class })
@EnableMetrics

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        .....................
        .....................
```

and error controller as below

```
@Component
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/error")
public class CustomErrorController extends BasicErrorController {

    public CustomErrorController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
        super(errorAttributes);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public String error() {
        return "Error handling";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this kind of solution, but, it seems that your request mapping is not right.

The request mapping of CustomErrorController is '/error', and in

```
@RequestMapping(value = PATH)
public String error() {
    return "Error handling";
}
```

There is a another '/error' in request mapping path. Then the url for this error handler is '/error/error'.

Answer (score 0):

You have `@RequestMapping("/error")` annotation on your controller and second `@RequestMapping("/error")` on your method. This results in `/error/error` mapping, not the `/error` mapping as you specified in `getErrorPath()` method and maybe in your configuration (application.properties, server.path.error).